# What are the commands for restarting a service after a file is changed in Chef?

Tags: chef

I am unable to figure out the correct solution in that if only when a file is updated, i.e. a conf file of a service, then the service is restarted (stopped and then started).

This is what I have in my `foo.rb` file.

```
cookbook_file '/etc/foo/foo.conf' do
  source 'foo.conf'
  action :touch
end

service 'foo' do
  subscribes :restart, 'file[/etc/foo/foo.conf]', :immediately
end
```

And what I got after running `sudo chef-client` on the server

```
cookbook_file[/etc/foo/foo.conf] action touch
    - update content in file /etc/foo/foo.conf from 695507 to 06105e

* service[foo] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
```

From what I understand, it recognized the file changed, but the service wasn't restarted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

subscribes must match the resource being subscribed to. It won't give you any errors if it doesn't though so you want

```
cookbook_file '/etc/foo/foo.conf' do
  source 'foo.conf'
  action :create
end

service 'foo' do
  subscribes :restart, 'cookbook_file[/etc/foo/foo.conf]', :immediately
end
```

Alternatively, you can do it the other way round i.e. have the cookbook_file notify the service that it needs to restart.

```
cookbook_file '/etc/foo/foo.conf' do
  source 'foo.conf'
  action :create
  notifies :restart, 'service[foo]', :immediately
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. This helped! What is odd is that option one works for one service, but doesn't for another. And vice versa for option two. For example, my rsyslog service option two works, but doesn't if I use option one. While my 'foo' service only works with option one.
Also, I needed to change the action from `touch` to `create` for either option to work.